# while comapring two values it showing String index out of range: -1

Tags: java, selenium

i want minimum price of a item comparing from flipkart and amazon site.i am searching for a particular phone in both site

```
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws InterruptedException {
        ArrayList<String[]> data1 = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        String[] entriesArr = null;
        String[] entriesArr1 = null;  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Seleniumjava\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
           WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();                   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //open flipkart
          driver.get("https:/www.flipkart.com");
//xpath for close the popup
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='✕']")).click();
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='O8ZS_U']/input")).sendKeys("Redmi 7 ( 32 MB , 2 GB ) Black");
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='O8ZS_U']/input")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
                    List<WebElement> phonenames = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='_3wU53n']"));
                    List<WebElement> phoneprice = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK']"));
                    for( int i=0;i<phonenames.size();i++)
                    {
                        if(phonenames.get(i).getText().contains("Redmi 7 (Eclipse Black, 32 GB)")) 
                        {
                            entriesArr = new String[]{phonenames.get(i).getText().toString(), phoneprice.get(i).getText().toString() };
                            data1.add(entriesArr);
                        }
                    }
            driver.close();
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Selenium-java\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
                    WebDriver driver1 = new ChromeDriver();
                    driver1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //open amazon site
                    driver1.get("https:/www.amazon.in");
            driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']")).sendKeys("Redmi 7 ( 32 MB , 2 GB ) Black");
                    driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    List< WebElement> phonenames2 = driver1.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal']"));
                    List< WebElement> phoneprice1 = driver1.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='a-offscreen']"));
                    for( int j=0;j<phonenames2.size();j++) {
                        if(phonenames2.get(j).getText().contains("Redmi 7 (Eclipse Black, 2GB RAM, 32GB Storage)")) {
                            entriesArr1 = new String[]{phonenames2.get(j).getText().toString(), phoneprice1.get(j).getText().toString() };
                            System.out.println(entriesArr1 );
                            System.out.println(entriesArr1.length);
                            data1.add(entriesArr1);
                        }
                    }
                    driver1.close();

                    String[] d = getMinPhonePrice(data1);
                    System.out.print(d[0] + ", " + d[1]);
                }
    //method for minimum phone price
                public static String[] getMinPhonePrice(ArrayList<String[]> data{
                    int value_min = Integer.parseInt(data.get(0)[1].substring(1).replace(",", ""));
                    String key_min="";
                    for(int i=1;i<data.size();i++) {
                        int value = Integer.parseInt(data.get(i)[1].substring(1).replace(",", ""));
                        if(value < value_min) {
                            value_min=value;
                            key_min=data.get(i)[0];
                        }
                    }
                    String[] d = {key_min,String.valueOf(value_min)};
                    return d;
                }
            }
```

when i run my code it showing  String index out of range: -1 in the line int value = Integer.parseInt(data.get(i)[1].substring(1).replace(",", ""));

Comment: This is true `for(int i=1;i<data.size();i++) {` ? should not `for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++) { `?

Comment: @Frian yes its true.because i am taking 0th value as value_min.so to comapre 1st value to 2nd value i am start loop from 1

Comment: data1=[{"redmi7","rs9,280"},{"redmi7","rs8,144"},{"redmi7","rs7,999"}]

Comment: `redmi7, 7999` Is this the value you want ?

Comment: yes,i want the lowest price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add some sleep for wait a load page after enter click, and your wrong select a locator `By.xpath("//span[@class='a-offscreen']")`, the locator doesn't given any text `=""`, so when you use `.substring(1)` it will cause error `String index out of range: -1`, please try this bellow code.

```
public static void main(String arg[]) throws InterruptedException {
    ArrayList<String[]> data1 = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String[] entriesArr = null;
    String[] entriesArr1 = null;  

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Seleniumjava\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //open flipkart
    driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com");

    //xpath for close the popup
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='✕']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='O8ZS_U']/input")).sendKeys("Redmi 7 ( 32 MB , 2 GB ) Black");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='O8ZS_U']/input")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

    //I'm edit here
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    List<WebElement> phonenames = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='_3wU53n']"));
    List<WebElement> phoneprice = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK']"));
    for( int i=0;i<phonenames.size();i++){
        if(phonenames.get(i).getText().contains("Redmi 7 (Eclipse Black, 32 GB)")) {
            entriesArr = new String[]{phonenames.get(i).getText().toString(), phoneprice.get(i).getText().toString() };
            data1.add(entriesArr);
        }
    }
    driver.close();

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Seleniumjava\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver1 = new ChromeDriver();

    driver1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //open amazon site
    driver1.get("https:/www.amazon.in");
    driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']")).sendKeys("Redmi 7 ( 32 MB , 2 GB ) Black");
    driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    List< WebElement> phonenames2 = driver1.findElements(By.xpath("//a//span[@class='a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal']"));
    //I'm edit here
    List< WebElement> phoneprice1 = driver1.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='a-price' and @data-a-size='l']"));

    for( int j=0;j<phonenames2.size();j++) {
        if(phonenames2.get(j).getText().contains("Redmi 7 (Eclipse Black, 2GB RAM, 32GB Storage)")) {
            entriesArr1 = new String[]{phonenames2.get(j).getText().toString(), phoneprice1.get(j).getText().toString() };
            data1.add(entriesArr1);
        }
    }
    driver1.close();

    String[] d = getMinPhonePrice(data1);
    System.out.println(d[0] + ", " + d[1]);
}

//method for minimum phone price
public static String[] getMinPhonePrice(ArrayList<String[]> data){
    int value_min = Integer.parseInt(data.get(0)[1].substring(1).replace(",", ""));
    String key_min="";

    for(int i=1;i<data.size();i++) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(data.get(i)[1].substring(1).replace(",", ""));
        if(value < value_min) {
            value_min=value;
            key_min=data.get(i)[0];
        }
    }
    String[] d = {key_min,String.valueOf(value_min)};
    return d;
}
```

Comment: this one same code what i am writing in my code.this one also showing same error  String index out of range: -1

Comment: Welcome, nice to help you !